# git checkout -f results in modified, unstaged files

Tags: git, website-deployment

For my website I have a *bare repository* (where I push to) and a clone with working directory which serves as document root.

In the bare repository I've setup a `post-receive` hook to auto-update the website:

```
#!/bin/sh
WEB_DIR=/var/www/www.mysite.com

# remove any untracked files and directories
git --work-tree=${WEB_DIR} clean -fd

# force checkout of the latest deploy
git --work-tree=${WEB_DIR} checkout --force
```

Unfortunately, after a push to the bare repository the changes do show up in the documentroot, but as but they show as **unstaged changes**. 
I then have to clean everything up by doing a `git checkout -- <files>` followed by a `git pull`.

Obviously the idea is that this works out of the box, if I have to do the cleanup+pull manually I might as well remove the `post-receive` hook.

I read it's better to use checkout in the post receive than a pull in various locations so I don't know if that would be a good change...

I'm not a git expert so I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm missing? The solution does seem to work for a lot of people as I've found it in several tutorials out there.

Comment: I've used the script from here: http://grokcode.com/792/deploy-with-git-push/ - Although I found the "checkout -f" in a couple other places about the same subject and they also just used that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### That's confusing

So right now what you've got is (e.g.):

```
/repos
    /mysite
        /.git 
            ...
/var
    /www
        /www.mysite.com
            /.git
                ...
            index.htm
            ...
```

Nothing strange there. However the hook in use is mis-matching things leaving the working copy's git repository out of sync with the checked-out files:

```
/repos
    /mysite
        /.git <- This git dir
            ...
/var
    /www
        /www.mysite.com <- This working copy
            index.htm
            ...
```

The git directory *for* the working copy is ignored. That makes things quite confusing - the working copy files are checked out to match the bare repository's state ignoring whatever is the working copy's own git info.

### Make it simple

Instead of that do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# see http://serverfault.com/q/107608/108287
# for why you can't just run git pull with no arguments

WEB_DIR=/var/www/www.mysite.com

cd $WEB_DIR

# Remove the comments after verifying that it works to reduce noise
git --git-dir $WEB_DIR/.git fetch # > /dev/null
git --git-dir $WEB_DIR/.git checkout --force # > /dev/null
git --git-dir $WEB_DIR/.git clean -fd # > /dev/null
```

I.e. push to the bare repository and then simulate exactly what you'd do manually, change directory pull and clean. That will update the working copy's files *and* git repository such that things are in sync.

Comment: Apparently where I was mistaken is that the doc-root should be a git repository. The tutorials just setup the post-receive hook making the bare repostory believe it has a working folder, which is the docroot. I've moved the .git folder out of the docroot and it seems to work, although I don't know if I really want remove the git-information from that folder...

Comment: Yes indeed. I agree with you fully. I didn't realise that this would be the result and I do prefer a docroot with its git info intact (so we can see if someone messed around with files). So your solution seems to be the better one. Thanks.